# I am trying to find the number of vowels in a string, but its returning 0 every time I run it. What is the problem with it?

Tags: java

```
public static int numberVowels(String s, int start, int end) {
    int total = 0;

    if (start == end)
        return total;

    else if (s.charAt(start) == 'a' || s.charAt(start) == 'e' || s.charAt(start) == 'i' || s.charAt(start) == 'o' ||
        s.charAt(start) == 'u') {

        total++;
        return numberVowels(s, start + 1, end);

    } else
        return numberVowels(s, start + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  Questions of the form "here's some code, please debug it for me" are off-topic.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that `total` is a local variable defined inside the function. If you define it outside, then your code will work. But you don't need the `total` variable. Assuming `end` is `s.length`:

```
public static int numberVowels (String s,int start, int end) { 

    if (start == end)
      return 0;

    if(s.charAt(start) == 'a' || s.charAt(start) == 'e' ||s.charAt(start) == 'i' ||s.charAt(start) == 'o' ||
    s.charAt(start) == 'u'){

        return 1 + numberVowels(s, start +1, end);

    }else 
          return numberVowels(s, start +1, end);
}
```